# Create query builder that the source table (FROM) is a join table in TypeORM

Tags: sql, typescript, postgresql, typeorm

I'm trying to implement the following SQL in TypeORM using `QueryBuilder`:

```sql
SELECT
  user_places.user_id,
  place.mpath
FROM
  public.user_root_places_place user_places
INNER JOIN
  public.place place
  ON place.id = user_places.place_id
```

The entities are:

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @Column({ unique: true, primary: true })
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Place)
  @JoinTable()
  rootPlaces: Place[];
}

@Entity()
export class Place {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  mpath: string;
}
```

When you create a query builder you have to use some entity or table but the join table is "hidden" by TypeORM

---

*I know I can replace the inner join table order and it will solve the problem but I'm looking for when the source table is the join table*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use the generated name just specify explicitly the join table name

```
@Entity()
export class User {
  @Column({ unique: true, primary: true })
  id: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Place)
  @JoinTable({
    name: 'user_places' // <---
  })
  rootPlaces: Place[];
}
```

And then:

```
createQueryBuilder('user_places')
  .select(['user_places.userId', 'place.mpath'])
  .innerJoin(Place, 'place', 'place.id = user_places.place_id')
  .getMany();
```